# Remove google adsense code from android app webview

Tags: wordpress, adsense

In wordpress-backend in function.php, i have added google adsense code to display ads in between blog post contents. The blog contents are been displayed in website and app side both and both are fetched from same table.

So, after adding adsense code in website, the adsense code is displayed in android app blog contents also.

How can we remove the adsense code from android app webview without using any plugins.